# Using PHP to pull data from Access Database PHP Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): 4 is not a valid ODBC result resource in EditRecord.php on line 91

Tags: php, html, ms-access

I'm trying to create a set of webpages that work together to allow users to view, delete, and edit rows of a MS Access database using PHP.

Membership.php shows a list of the names of members in the Access database.  Their names are also hyperlinks that, when clicked, take users to another page EditRecord.php where all of information on the member whose name was clicked on Membership.php is displayed in text boxes with the option to completely delete the record, or just update certain fields.

Membership.php and EditRecord.php are displayed below.  The error code is for line 91 of my source for EditRecord.php, but I cut some things out of this post for privacy.  Instead, the line has been marked like so:

**//--------This is the error line----------**

**code**

[Membership.php]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Accounts.css">
<style type="text/javascript" src="Validate.js"></style>
<style type="text/javascript" scr="Redirect.js"></style>
<style type="text/javascript" src="Utilities.js"></style>
<title>Member Information Input</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
<?php
//Establish data connection using external file
require("connection.php");

//Issue SQL SELECT Statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Membership";

//Stores any results that match the search term.        
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

//Set counter for search results to zero 
$results = 0;

//Iterates through search results and prints information on records that match  
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))     

{
$results += 1;
echo '<p><a href="EditMember.php?ID=' . $row['ID'] . '" id="popup">' .   $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "</a></p>";


}

?>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

[EditRecord.php]

```
<?php

//Retrieve ID value - if the page is loading for the first time, use $_GET[]. If the   
//delete or edit button has been clicked, use $_POST[]

if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {
$userID = $_GET['ID'];
}

else {
$userID=$_POST['ID'];
}

//Establish data connection
require("connection.php");

//If the Delete Button is clicked 

if (isset($_POST['DelBtn'])) {
//Issue SQL Statement to Delete Selected Record
$sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM Membership WHERE ID = $userID";

//Execute the SQL Delete Query
$rsDelete = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlDelete);

if(odbc_num_rows($rsDelete) == 1) {
    echo "Record successfully deleted!";
}
}

//If the Edit Button is clicked
else if (isset($_POST['EditBtn'])) {

//Collect form field values in scalar variables
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$City = $_POST['City'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'];

//Issue SQL Statement to Update Selected Record
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Membership SET FirstName = '$FirstName', LastName = '$LastName', Address = '$Address', City = '$City', State = '$State'" . 
"Email='$Email', Gender = '$Gender', Comments = '$Comments'  WHERE ID = $userID";

//Execute the SQL UPDATE Query
$rsEdit = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlUpdate);

if(odbc_num_rows($rsEdit) == 1) {
    echo "Record successfully updated!";
}
}

//Issue SQL SELECT Statement to Select Record to Edit or Delete

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Membership WHERE ID = $userID";

//Execute the SQL Query

$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
odbc_close($conn);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Accounts.css">
<style type="text/javascript" src="Validate.js"></style>
<style type="text/javascript" src="Utilities.js"></style>
<title>Member Information Input</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="EditMember.php" name="EditForm">
        <?php
        // Loop through and display the recordset returned by SELECT statement. Display the record values in HTML Text Boxes
                    **//--------This is the error line----------
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
        ?>**

        First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName']?>"><br>
        Last Name:  <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $row['LastName']?>"><br>
        Address:    <input type="text" name="Address" value="<?php echo $row['Address']?>"><br>
        City:       <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="<?php echo $row['City']?>"><br>
        State:      <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="<?php echo $row['State']?>"><br>
        Email:      <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $row['Email']?>"><br>
        Gender:     <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="<?php echo $row['Gender']?>"><br>
        Comments:   <input type="text" name="Comments" value="<?php echo $row['Comments']?>"><br><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>" >

        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <input type="submit" name="EditBtn" value="Edit Record">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="DelBtn" value="Delete Record">

    </form>



</div>

<div id="footer">
    <?php require("Footer.php"); ?>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I also find this strange, because there are five records in my database, not four. Is that because it starts counting at zero?

Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your `delete` and `update` part working?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling `odbc_close()` and closing the connection before your loop calls `odbc_fetch_array()`. You need to leave the connection open until after you've fetched all of the rows.

Also, the "4" in the error message does not refer to a number of rows or anything like that; it's just the numeric representation of result identifier for the resource created by the `odbc_exec()` call.